# After Windows 10 wakes up, WIFI won't work

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I have a Lenovo R61 Thinkpad.

If I close the lid, Windows goes to sleep.

When I open the lid, Windows wakes up, however, after waking up, WIFI won't connect to my network.

> Checking network requirements.
>
> Can't connect to this network.

Comment: If You open the Windows Mobility Center by pressing `Win` button + `x`, does the wireless appears to be turned off?

Comment: There is no wireless section in mobility center when I open it, even now when wireless is working @Divin3

Comment: Are You using a docking station? I have experience that it can cause some headaches.

Comment: No, no docking station @Divin3.

Comment: Same problem here with a Dell Pavilion dv6000. Wifi worked fined w/ previous versions of Windows.

Comment: +1 Good question. Same issue here with Thinkpad X201S and Toshiba NB100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did two things: I installed an updated device driver, which made wireless intermittently become connected after waking up from sleep, and also un-ticked "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power", in the "Power Management" tab of the wireless network adapter properties.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem with the WiFi adapters in recent Lenovo laptops. It's probably a driver problem, though I'm not ruling out just a lot of bad hardware. In either case, Lenovo has apparently forgotten how to do QA, because this problem has existed for over a year across multiple hardware lines. As far as I can tell, it's not OS-specific; I've seen it on Win8 and 8.1 as well.

You can try solutions like what @Divin3 recommended, but if that doesn't work the workaround is to just disable-and-re-enable the card. This used to be difficult, requiring Admin and so on, but if your OS offers "Airplane Mode" (in Win8.1, it's at the top of the WiFi connection sidebar) you can turn that on and then off again to bounce the WiFi adapter. Sorry for the lack of Win10-specific advice; none of my Win10 installs are running on bare metal on a laptop yet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that You did try to update and reinstall all drivers, I did some research about this, and found a similar problem. This might be the same in your case. The only one way to find out is to try this:

> 1. Make sure you have logged in an Administrator Account.
> 2. Go to Control Panel > Device Manager > Network adapters and then click on plus (+) sign to expand the list of available adapters.
> 3. Right click on Wireless Lan Card and then click on Properties.
> 4. In Advanced tab, you will see some entries like – IEEE802.11h, Power Saving mode, Radio On/Off, SmartScan etc. Click on each and then
>      on Value – select Enable and constantly awake.
> 5. On Power management Tab, deselect – Allow the computer to turn off the device to save power.
> 6. Click OK

The only problem with this is, it might reduce your battery lifetime.